# Bootstrap sticky highlight the wrong div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I used sticky function with highlight the navbar when it reached the top. It's working fine when the header is small / the device is smaller than the desktop. For desktop when I click the left nav div, it's taking the correct section in the right. But the nav active class is showing different. Please check the gif file. I clicked the section 1, it displays section 1 in right but its highlight the section 3 in left. I want to highlight the correct section in left too. Please help.

[image]

```js
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".orderonlinediv ul li a");
let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll(".maincatdiv section");

let lastId;
let cur = [];

// This should probably be throttled.
// Especially because it triggers during smooth scrolling.
// https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle
// You could do like...
// window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
//    _.throttle(doThatStuff, 100);
// });
// Only not doing it here to keep this Pen dependency-free.

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;

  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

    if (
      section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
      section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
    ) {
      link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
      link.classList.remove("current");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.sticky{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.orderonlinediv {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.orderonlinediv ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.orderonlinediv li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.orderonlinediv a {
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}

.orderonlinediv ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orderonlinediv ul li a.current {
  color: #ef3b51 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Website<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <nav class="orderonlinediv sticky">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-8">Section 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-9">Section 9</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <main class="maincatdiv">
        <section id="section-1">
          <h1>Section 1</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
          <h1>Section 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-3">
          <h1>Section 3</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-4">
          <h1>Section 4</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-5">
          <h1>Section 5</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-6">
          <h1>Section 6</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-7">
          <h1>Section 7</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-8">
          <h1>Section 8</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-9">
          <h1>Section 9</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your `fromTop` is taken from the top of the body so the whole height of the header is included in your calculation. So try to get height of the header and remove it.

Comment: @MaxiGui you're right. I fixed the issue. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: You welcome. I still made a proper answer in case some user get on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated below code in js and its working fine now. I got the height of the header and remove it from the js. Thanks to @MaxiGui

```
var heightoftopdiv = $('header').height();
let fromTop = window.scrollY - heightoftopdiv;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because otherwise section top start from 0 like if there is no header.
So get the header height as followed:

```
let header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].offsetHeight
```

And then 2 options:

1. Demo 1: add it to your section calculation in the if as followed:

   `section.offsetTop + header <= fromTop && section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight + header > fromTop`
2. Demo 2: Remove this height from `fromTop`:

   `let fromTop = window.scrollY - header;`

```js
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".orderonlinediv ul li a");
let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll(".maincatdiv section");

let lastId;
let cur = [];

// This should probably be throttled.
// Especially because it triggers during smooth scrolling.
// https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle
// You could do like...
// window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
//    _.throttle(doThatStuff, 100);
// });
// Only not doing it here to keep this Pen dependency-free.

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].offsetHeight ////// <<<<<< Add this
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;

  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
    

    ////// Add header height in if as followed
    if (
      section.offsetTop + header <= fromTop &&
      section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight + header > fromTop
    ) {
      link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
      link.classList.remove("current");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.sticky{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.orderonlinediv {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.orderonlinediv ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.orderonlinediv li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.orderonlinediv a {
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}

.orderonlinediv ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orderonlinediv ul li a.current {
  color: #ef3b51 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Website<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <nav class="orderonlinediv sticky">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <main class="maincatdiv">
        <section id="section-1">
          <h1>Section 1</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
          <h1>Section 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-3">
          <h1>Section 3</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-4">
          <h1>Section 4</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-5">
          <h1>Section 5</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-6">
          <h1>Section 6</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-7">
          <h1>Section 7</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo 2:

```js
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".orderonlinediv ul li a");
let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll(".maincatdiv section");

let lastId;
let cur = [];

// This should probably be throttled.
// Especially because it triggers during smooth scrolling.
// https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle
// You could do like...
// window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
//    _.throttle(doThatStuff, 100);
// });
// Only not doing it here to keep this Pen dependency-free.

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].offsetHeight ////// <<<<<< Add this
  let fromTop = window.scrollY - header;

  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
    

    ////// Add header height in if as followed
    if (
      section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
      section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
    ) {
      link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
      link.classList.remove("current");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.sticky{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.orderonlinediv {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.orderonlinediv ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.orderonlinediv li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.orderonlinediv a {
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}

.orderonlinediv ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.orderonlinediv ul li a.current {
  color: #ef3b51 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Website<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <nav class="orderonlinediv sticky">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <main class="maincatdiv">
        <section id="section-1">
          <h1>Section 1</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
          <h1>Section 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-3">
          <h1>Section 3</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-4">
          <h1>Section 4</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-5">
          <h1>Section 5</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-6">
          <h1>Section 6</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
        <section id="section-7">
          <h1>Section 7</h1>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?<br>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, blanditiis expedita? Earum
            eligendi pariatur quaerat quos expedita ab quibusdam ratione veniam in, mollitia fuga repudiandae?</p>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```